# mono - the requested feature is not implemented - what feature?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm receiving this error when I start my application but I have NO idea what feature isn't implemented.  It doesn't print anything to the console or tell me what isn't implemented.

Is there a way to figure this out? The only thing I have to go on is this error message that appears in a window:
[image]

Interestingly enough my application does start after I click ok, but I'd like to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimize to systray is my first guess. That wasn't implemented last time I looked.

But you might be able to find a stack trace in Windows' Event Viewer -- Application Log

Comment: That would make complete sense, let me dig into that.  There is a systray icon on windows so that would pan out.

Comment: Found out it was due to System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon being initialized and having visible set to true during InitializeComponent